# Read app.config using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, app-config, linq-to-objects

I have implemented (using `System.Configuration` namespace) and configured next `App.config` structure:

```
<bot>
    <strategies>
        <add name="TestStrategy" type="Bot.Strategy.Test" >
            <indicators>
                <add name="Foo" type="Bot.Indicators.Foo, Bot" />
                <add name="Bar" type="Bot.Indicators.Bar, Bot" />  
            </indicators>
            <orders>
                <add id="123" amount="0.1" />
            </orders>
        </add>
    </strategies>
</bot>
```

for next classes:

```
class TestStrategy : IStrategy
{
    public TestStrategy(IEnumerable<IIndicator> indicators, IEnumerable<Order> orders) { }
}

interface IIndicator { }

class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

So how can I read my App.config to instantiate `IEnumerable<IStrategy>` calling the constructor of each with appropriate `IEnumerable<IIndicator>` and `IEnumerable<Order>` using LINQ?

I have already next:

```
var section = ((BotSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("bot"));
return from strategy in section.Strategies
       let strategyType = Type.GetType(strategy.Type)
       where !strategyType.IsInterface && !strategyType.IsAbstract && typeof(IStrategy).IsAssignableFrom(strategyType)
       select (IStrategy)Activator.CreateInstance(strategyType, ?);
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't skip types that aren't concrete (as you do in the `where` clause), but I would throw a specific exception describing  the actual problem, or let the `Activator` throw that exception for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `BotSection` is defined correctly, you can do this (note the sub queries):

```
return
    from strategy in section.Strategies
    let strategyType = Type.GetType(strategy.Type)
    where !strategyType.IsInterface && !strategyType.IsAbstract
        && typeof(IStrategy).IsAssignableFrom(strategyType)
    let indicators = (
        from indicator in strategy.Indicators
        let indicatorType = Type.GetType(indicator.Type)
        select (IIndicator)Activator.CreateInstance(indicatorType))
    let orders = (
        from order in strategy.Orders
        let id = order.Id
        select new Order { Id = order.Id, Amount = order.Amount })
    select (IStrategy)Activator.CreateInstance(strategyType, indicators, orders);
```

Comment: You could refactor the creation of the `strategyType` and the sub queries to a method and do `select CreateStrategy(strategy)`, but that doesn't really remove the nested queries. I don't know any other way.